# Which users have close vote privileges both here and on ELL?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, ell

Not too long ago, I unlocked the cast close and reopen votes privilege... on ELL. Here on ELU I've had that privilege for a pretty long time, since I just recently unlocked the very last privilege (site statistics at 25,000 rep).

In any case, getting to 3,000 reputation is a pretty significant milestone. It's an important way that users can influence the site, and the influence is greater than the sum of its parts when you have it on both ELU and ELL because of how linked the two sites are. More significantly, people who have close votes on ELL should have a decent knowledge of the scope of the site, which is important when deciding if a question is off-topic: is it on-topic on ELL (making migration an option) or is it off-topic on both sites?

Thus, my question is: which users have close/reopen privileges on both ELU and ELL?

Comment: Why do you think that "*the influence is greater than the sum of its parts when you have it on both ELU and ELL*"?

Comment: @user240918 Because you can vote to close the same question twice: first by migrating, then by closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Mmm... never thought about that. I think we should probably save more questions rather than looking for any possible reason to VTC them...as a general attitude.

Comment: @user240918 That was only an example. Another example is if you disagree with users who migrated a specific question to ELL, you can cast a close vote on the migrated question and if it gets closed the migration is rejected and you can cast a reopen vote on the original ELU question. (Although I might be the only one who could come up with a convoluted plan like that :P)

Comment: The edit helped me understand your purpose a lot better! +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the magic of T-SQL I've found the answer. You can run my query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/909289/users-with-privileges-elu-vs-ell?RepuationThreshold=3000), with the data being updated weekly. There are currently 57 users with close/reopen privileges on both sites (not including CMs, except Catija because she has the rep).

Actually, with this query I did one better than what I asked: it works for any privilege. Simply enter a number in the "RepuationThreshold" corresponding to the privilege level you want to see users for. For example, 500 shows users with the minimum review privileges, 3000 is close/reopen privileges, 10000 is users who can see deleted posts & vote to delete questions.

Another significant thing I learned from this query is that there are 5 people who have attained 25,000 on both sites.

Here's teh codez:

```
create table #Yall (
 globalid int,
 ELUid int,
 site varchar (3)
);

use [StackExchange.English]; -- Just to be sure

insert into #yall select accountid, id, 'ELU' from users where reputation >=##RepuationThreshold##;

use [StackExchange.ELL];

insert into #yall select accountid, 0, 'ELL' from users where reputation >=##RepuationThreshold##;

use [StackExchange.English];

select ELUid as [User Link] from #yall where site='ELU' and globalid in (select globalid from #yall where site='ELL')
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Heinz magical number *also* include users whose accounts have a very sporadic activity or have been inactive for two years or longer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm curious, what was the word "Heinz" in your comment intended to be? I ask because the only actual "Heinz magical number" I'm personally familiar with is 57, the mysterious one on their ketchup bottles.

Comment: @DanBron bingo! "There are currently 57 users"